# Invalid soapenv:Envelope when using spring WebServiceTemplate

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I am having difficulty in calling WebService using Spring WebServiceTemplate, server response with "Fault occurred while processing."I have Soap UI project that works, I compared outgoing messages and the difference in **soapenv:Envelope** .

**In Soap UI I have:**

> soapenv:Envelope
>   xmlns:ser="http://service.server.webservices.checkpoint.tta.com"
>   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

**In Spring:**

SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

My spring config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

 <bean id="marshaller"
    class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="contextPath"
      value="com.test.checkpoint" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
  <property name="interceptors" ref="securityInterceptor"/>
  <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
  <property name="defaultUri" value="http://dev.checkpoint.test.com/app/services/CPWSSearchService"/>
 </bean>


 <bean id="securityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
  <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/>
  <property name="securementUsername" value="test"/>
  <property name="securementPassword" value="test"/>
  <property name="securementPasswordType" value="PasswordText"/>
 </bean>
 

</beans>
```

My Java Code:

```html
PerformSearch request=new ObjectFactory().createPerformSearch();
        request.setSearchUrl("Some text query");
        PerformSearchResponse response= (PerformSearchResponse) client.marshalSendAndReceive(request );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to include ser namespace in your soap request, rest is fine,
    xmlns:ser="http://service.server.webservices.checkpoint.tta.com". I don't know in which part of your code, you are creating soap envelope.

Comment: Hi kingAm, yes the problem with envelope , I don't explicitly create it , I use WebServiceTemplate and I can't find how change envelope using this template.

Comment: I added envelope to request :    PerformSearchResponse response= (PerformSearchResponse) client.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
                SoapEnvelope envelope=((SoapMessage) message).getEnvelope();
                envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ser","http://service.server.webservices.checkpoint.tta.com");
            }
        });       but the problem still appears, I think it can be related to JAXB

Comment: You are receiving fault response that means your request is hitting the server but format is not right. Try to debug your code and see your request at various breakpoints. Also in soap fault it may be indicating why it is getting failed. I am unable to pin point your issue, may be someone else jump in.

Comment: Thanks kingAm, I fixed it , the request was OK. I send some search query to service and the problem related with syntactic of this query. I figure out it when I looked to description of fault code (realized that exceptions occurs on server and structure of soap request is OK) . I had <soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring></soapenv:Fault>  .  This link was helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_fault.htm  . Thanks for helping!